# Как закомпилировать .java файл в .class?

Tags: компиляция

помогите не понимаю, нужно закомпилировать .java файл в обратно в .class как это сделать?

Comment: RTFM. Любые книга по Java, мануал, видеокурс "для начинающих" не просто содержат ответ на этот вопрос. Они начинаются с этого.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой код:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы скомпилировать данную программу перейдите в каталог с .java файлом и введите:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

При этом файл должен называться так же как и ваш класс.

Для запуска скомпилированного файла введите в том же каталоге:

```
java -classpath . HelloWorld
```